# Are "burro" and "aburrir" related?

Tags: etimología, animales

Is the word *aburrir* (*get bored*) etymologically related to the word *burro* (*donkey*)?

They seem to share a common root (*burr*). Plus, there is a Spanish saying:

> Solo los burros se aburren

Comment: I've often heard this funny silly sentence. `— Me aburro... — !Pues cómprate un burro!` ;) It's just a play on words because of the similarity in spelling of both words.

Comment: I invented a Spanish Tom Swifty: —El asno no hace nada — dijo Tomás, aburrido.

Comment: El toro se atora, la orca te ahorca y el pollo me apoya.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

No, *aburrir* comes from the Latin *abhorrere*, related with the English word *abhor*.

*Burro* or *borrico* comes also from the Latin, but from a different root, *burricus* (caballejo).

> [**aburrir**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=0ESK81y)
>   Del lat. abhorrēre.

> [**abhor**](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=abhor&searchmode=none)
>   mid-15c., from Latin abhorrere

> [**borrico**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=5w8qGIh), ca
>   Del lat. tardío burrīcus 'caballo pequeño'.